# Jhipster - unable to Use a Gateway app when deploying everything on docker host except the Gateway itself, Mixed Docker and locally deployment

Tags: docker, microservices, jhipster, keycloak, gateway

I have some JHipster Spring Microservice and gateway projects. I deployed all of them on a host using docker except the gateway. I started the gateway on another host.

I use Keycloak for OAuth authentication.

Everything works fine when i deploy all of the microservices and databases and Gateways as docker containers on a docker network using docker-compose.

But it doesn't work when i just deploy everything on docker except the gateway.i mean if the gateway resides outside of docker-created network. the motivation for this action is that I just want my UI programmer to up and run the gateway on his own PC, and use microservices which are deployed on server host. Just for ease of UI development in need to up and run this sole gateway using `gradle bootRun -Pprod`.

I used a technique to assign a separate IP to each container on my docker network. This technique is called Docker MacVLan networking. so that every container in the host have a separate IP address in physical network and each of these containers are visible on other hosts in the network.

the problem is that in normal docker deployment (when gateway is deployed in a docker network in same host) everything works fine. but in my scenario after successful login, every microservice return `error 401`.

in microservice it says this error:

```
o.s.s.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate   : Setting request Accept header to [application/json, application/x-jackson-smile, application/cbor, application/*+json]
o.s.s.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate   : GET request for "http://keycloak:9080/auth/realms/jhipster/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo" resulted in 401 (Unauthorized); invoking error handler
n.m.b.s.o.CachedUserInfoTokenServices    : Could not fetch user details: class org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.resource.OAuth2AccessDeniedException, Unable to obtain a new access token for resource 'null'. The provider manager is not configured to support it.
p.a.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter : Authentication request failed: error="invalid_token", error_description="token string here"
```

[image: SSO 401 is Happening]

it says that your token is invalid. the same mechanism just works when everything is deployed in same host in docker. is it for the Keycloak that prevents the token to validate for external hosts? i personally doubt that , because it didn't prevent me from logging into gateway successfully. and i just checked keycloak. its up by the command `-b 0.0.0.0`

Please help me up and run a gateway just by `gradle bootRun -Pprod`.

In summary I could rephrase my question to: ***i just want the UI Developer be able to test his angular/spring-gateway project in it's own PC while other services are deployed in powerful server using docker*** (authentication using ***Keycloak***). and it is not possible to deploy those other services on UI developers own PC. how to do it in JHipster?

Answer (score 0):

add server.use-forward-headers=true to your config when using the gateway